# Symfony4 does not get Environment Varbiables from vHost Configuration

Tags: php, apache, deployment, environment-variables, symfony4

I'm currently setting up an Webserver on a RaspberryPi with Raspbian 9 and want to deploy a productive Symfony4 Webpage on it.

For that case I created a vHost File in Apache2 with the needed Environment-Variables in it. But as I'm executing "composer install --no-dev" (because I don't want to use dotenv) I'm getting the error "**PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: APP_ENV environment variable is not defined. You need to define environment variables for configuration or add "symfony/dotenv" as a Composer dependency to load variables from a .env file.**"

When creating a test.php file in Symfonys Public Folder and querying "echo $_SERVER['APP_ENV']" I'm getting correctly the setted "prod" Variable.

Thanks for your help!

Attached the anonymized vHost File:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName gate.keeper
    ServerAlias www.gate.keeper

    DocumentRoot /var/www/gk3/public
    <Directory /var/www/gk3/public>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    # uncomment the following lines if you install assets as symlinks
    # or run into problems when compiling LESS/Sass/CoffeeScript assets
    # <Directory /var/www/gk3>
    #     Options FollowSymlinks
    # </Directory>

    # optionally disable the RewriteEngine for the asset directories
    # which will allow apache to simply reply with a 404 when files are
    # not found instead of passing the request into the full symfony stack
    <Directory /var/www/gk3/public/bundles>
        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine Off
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/gk3_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/gk3_access.log combined

    # optionally set the value of the environment variables used in the application
    SetEnv APP_ENV "prod"
    SetEnv APP_SECRET "secret"
    SetEnv DATABASE_URL "mysql://user:password@localhost:3306/db_name"
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run a composer command in your terminal, you're accessing to PHP on the command line environment, and you don't pass thru Apache and any configuration you did in the VirtualHost.

That said, you need to run the following command before execute **composer install --no-dev** in order to set the APP_ENV value:

```
export APP_ENV=prod
```